# adding comments during IntelliJ debug and line numbers get messed up

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm studying a program somebody wrote, and I want to go through it using debug while also adding comments. I'm not actually editing live code, just adding comments. When I do this, it seems like the line numbers get messed up in IntelliJ.

For example in the "Frames" section of the Debug window, the full stacktrace (for lack of a better term) is listed as usual, which lets you double click on any part of it and shows you the corresponding line in the corresponding file. But for the file where I've added comments, it's incorrect. The line number being used is the one that *would* have been correct had I not added a couple lines of comments.

In File->Settings I do have HotSwap enabled, although the checkbox technically says "Enable hot-swap agent for Groovy code." I don't know what Groovy is or if I'm using it.

Is there any way to get the line numbers to work when adding comments? Either manually forcing a reload or getting this to work automatically would be OK. I just don't want to have to restart the entire program.

Comment: Yes, this is common (even normal) behaviour.  The debugger starts with a known compiled version of your program.  If you add/remove code (even just comments) they are part of your 'view' but not part of the running (pre-modifications) code so the IDE and the running code are out of sync.  Hot-swap should work. You may need to re-run your code to get to the breakpoint again though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to reload the class every time you modify it, just like if you were making actual changes instead of just comments that change the line numbers.

So do either one of the following

```
Run | Reload Changed Classes
Build | Compile "class_name"
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reloading-classes.html